# Applying Fubini's theorem to inequality on norms

Tags: integration

Problem : If a>0 , prove that there exists c>0 depending only on n and a such that

$ c^{-1}(|x_1|^a+....+|x_n|^a) \leq |x|^a \leq c(|x_1|^a+....+|x_n|^a)$

Where I am stuck - THe book I am folloqing has mentioned this problem in the Fubini's theorem section and I am not able to see how can I apply the theorem in this case to get at the required inequality.

Note : $|x|$ is the eucliadean norm of $x \in R^n$

Comment: So is $|\cdot|^a$ any different from $|\cdot|$?

Comment: Yes , the first symbol represents the value of the norm raised to the power of a . While the later is simply the norm

Comment: But you stated $|x|^a$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$? Shouldn't it be the Euclidean norm to the power of $a$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Fubini here. I suspect it is because the author invokes this result later in this chapter where he will refer you to this exercise.

Anyway, how about this:
\begin{align}
|x|^a=\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}\right)^a\ge \left(\max_{i=1,2\cdots,n}|x_i|\right)^a=\max_{i=1,2\cdots,n}|x_i|^a\ge\frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^a\right)
\end{align}
in the meantime
\begin{align}
|x|^a&=\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}\right)^a\le\left(n\max_{i=1,2\cdots,n}|x_i|\right)^a\\
&= n^a\left(\max_{i=1,2\cdots,n}|x_i|\right)^a=n^a\max_{i=1,2\cdots,n}|x_i|^a\le n^a\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^a\right)
\end{align}
Now all you have to do is to find an appropriate $c$ such that $c\ge n^a$ and $\frac1c\le \frac1n$, so $c\ge \max(n,n^a)$.